# Shell script to find the last occurring line ID in a file and add a new one

Tags: bash, sed

I have a text file with the following format:

```
abc
def
...
...
ID=1
This is Entry1
ID=2
This is Entry2
...
ID=<N>
This is Entry<N>
xyz
...
```

How do I insert the following new entry into the text file before line "xyz"?

```
ID=N+1
This is Entry<N+1>
```

To complicate matters further the ID lines may not be in order in the file so it could be that the order is:

```
abc
def
...
ID=5
ID=2
ID=N
...
ID=9
...
xyz
```

(where N=10, the highest).

Is there a way of identifying what the highest occurring (numerically) ID line is in the file and then adding a new line "ID=" before the occurence of the line "xyz"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

another way in awk

```
awk -F= '/ID=/{x=$2>x?$2:x}FNR==NR{next}
/xyz/{print "ID="x+1"\nThis is entry<"x+1">"}1' test{,}
```

Comment: +1, but note that the use of brace expansions to get the input file name repeated is invalid in some shells.  (If it does not work, simply replace "test{,}" with "test test")

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for this:

```
awk -F'=' 'NR==FNR{if(/^ID=/)n=$2>n?$2:n;next}
           /^xyz$/{print "ID="++n;printf "whatEVER<%d>\n",n}7' file file
```

see this example:

```
kent$  cat f
abc
def
ID=5
ID=2
foo
ID=777
bar
ID=9
xyz


kent$  awk -F'=' 'NR==FNR{if(/^ID=/)n=$2>n?$2:n;next}/^xyz$/{print 
"ID="++n;printf "whatEVER<%d>\n",n}7' f f
abc
def
ID=5
ID=2
foo
ID=777
bar
ID=9
ID=778
whatEVER<778>
xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly get the maximum value:

```
val=$(grep -Po '(?<=ID=)\d*' file | sort -n | tail -1)
```

Then print it before the line `xyz`:

```
awk -v d="$val" '/xyz/ {print "This is entry", d+1} 1' file
```

To update the file, do redirect to a temporary file and then rewrite if no errors were found:

```
awk -v d="$val" '/xyz/ {print "This is entry", d+1} 1' file > tmp_file && mv tmp_file file
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
abc
def
...
...
ID=1
This is Entry1
ID=2
This is Entry2
...
ID=9
xyz
ID=23
alsjdflk
ID=2
$ d=$(grep -Po '(?<=ID=)\d*' a | sort -n | tail -1)
$ awk -v d="$d" '/xyz/ {print "This is entry", d+1} 1' a
abc
def
...
...
ID=1
This is Entry1
ID=2
This is Entry2
...
ID=9
This is entry 24
xyz
ID=23
alsjdflk
ID=2
```

See the implementation of the `grep | sort | tail` command:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=ID=)\d*' a 
1
2
9
23
2
$ grep -Po '(?<=ID=)\d*' a | sort -n
1
2
2
9
23
$ grep -Po '(?<=ID=)\d*' a | sort -n | tail -1
23
```

Comment: `sort -n` should not work when numbers will be greater than 9. It will not do natural sort of numbers that we human expect to see. `sort -V` should do the trick.

Comment: It works, because I previously do `grep` for the digits only.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the highest number with:

```
highest=$(sed -n '/^ID=/s/^ID=//p' filename | sort -nr | head -1)
new=$((highest + 1))
```

Then insert it into the file with:

```
sed -i .bak "/xyz/i\
ID=$new\
This is entry$new\
" filename
```

Comment: Thanks guys. Some great answers here!

Answer (score 0):

> identifying what the highest occurring (numerically) ID line is in the file and then adding a new line "ID=" *before* the occurrence of the line "xyz"?
>   
> [...]
>   ID lines may not be in order in the file

What about:

```
awk -F = '$1=="ID" { if($2>ID) ID=$2 }
          /^xyz/    { printf("ID=%d\nThis is entry%d\n",ID+1,ID+1) }
          1' testfile
```

Here is an usage example:

```
sh$ cat testfile
abc
def
...
...
ID=1
This is Entry1
ID=55
This is Entry55
...
ID=3
This is Entry3
xyz
...
sh$ awk -F = '$1=="ID" { if($2>ID) ID=$2 } /^xyz/ { printf("ID=%d\nThis is entry%d\n",ID+1,ID+1) } 1' testfile
abc
def
...
...
ID=1
This is Entry1
ID=55
This is Entry55
...
ID=3
This is Entry3
ID=56
This is entry56
xyz
...
```